# Rubbing noise when driving with clutch engaged?

Tags: clutch, jeep, drivetrain, wrangler

I am a complete newbie when it comes to jeeps (and cars in general). However, I am very good at fixing things... once I know what the problem is.

After a summer of riding with the top down I was used to the loud noise of the air going by, but once I put the top up at the beginning of winter I instantly noticed a rubbing noise coming from my drive train. I can only hear it when I am driving with the clutch engaged and the faster I am going the louder it is (so I know it's behind the transmission). I didn't think much of it because I only had the jeep for a month or so with the top up before I took it down for the summer. Now I have been driving it with the top up for a couple months and the rubbing noise has gotten louder.

I don't really like taking my car to the dealership because in the past they have completely made up problems that didn't exist - so I would love to figure this out at home. All help is appreciated.

Some info about my jeep --
It's an 04 Wrangler X. I bought it used spring of 2012 with 22k miles on it.
Everything related to the drivetrain is factory installed.
I make sure to check the fluids regularly and they don't seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

So you need to find out where on your drive train. Get your Jeep up off the ground so you can drive the wheels, and have a listen.

Likely places:

- Differential
- Universal joints on axles
- Tire rubbing on bodywork
- Brake pad rubbing against disc

Comment: Hmm.  Can't be the tire rubbing or the brakes because it's only when the clutch is engaged.  The noise is most noticeable when I am in a high gear (3 or 4 or 5).  I'm not that comfortable running my jeep in my garage in 5th gear - where should I do something like that?  And if it were the diff wouldn't it only make a rubbing noise while turning?

Comment: If you don't have the necessary lift or stands in your garage I'd probably suggest taking it along to a local mechanic. This will also have the advantage that they can listen as well, and will be in a very good position to identify the noise.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I think that's what I have to do.